# Limit upload speed with RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, limit, restsharp, throttling

Anyone knows if it's possible to throttle network bandwidth for uploads using RestSharp? I couldn't find any good solution, even by uploading the file manually. I'm also considering embedding an external solution, if it's too difficult to code.

Update: The problem is that our client don't always have good internet connection, so they need to make sure our app won't slow down other more important applications running. We've tried to suggest doing that on their proxy server, QoS, but they can't for some other reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: OK *"throttling network bandwidth for uploads"* maybe a solution for your problem, but how about posting your **real** problem. See [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). Does it apply to your question?

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question with the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs a solution to this problem, I've wrote my own upload with HTTPWebrequest and I'm controlling upload speed by myself. I think it's not possible with RestSharp, as you can find here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005308/328204